# Реализация кнопки вычитания матрицы

Tags: delphi

Есть программа. Подскажите как реализовать логическую функцию вычитания матрицы а(2,3), b(2,3)

```html
unit lab7;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    stg: TStringGrid;
    eCol: TEdit;
    eRow: TEdit;
    form: TButton;
    clea: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ess: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure cleaClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure formClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
// Процедура очистки таблицы. В процедуре использовано оператор with
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.cleaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j: integer;
begin
  with stg do
  begin
    for i := 0 to colcount-1 do
    for j := 0 to rowcount-1 do
      cells[i,j]:='';
  end;
    
end;
 // Формирование таблицы TStringGrid с именем STG та определения суммы элементов 
procedure TForm2.formClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j,s,n,m: integer;
begin
  n:=StrToInt(eCol.Text); // кол-во колонок таблицы
  m:=StrToInt(eRow.Text); // кол-во столбиков таблицы
  stg.ColCount:=n;
  stg.RowCount:=m;
  randomize;
    for i := 0 to n-1 do
      for j := 0 to m-1 do
        begin
          stg.Cells[i,j]:=IntToStr(random(10));
          s:=s+StrToInt(stg.Cells[i,j]);
        end;
  ess.Text := IntToStr(s);  // Запись результата в поле редактирования
end;

end.
```

Скрин программки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем именно сложность у вас? циклами вы вроде владеете и так

Comment: с циклами владею? - ну с горем пополам, если честно. сложность заключается в том, что перепробовал по разному реализовать а результат = нулевый

Comment: Если я правильно понял - у Вас вычитание матриц a - b. Значит должно быть две матрицы + вывод результата. У Вас сейчас одна, добавьте еще 2 таблицы. Потом ходите по столбцам и рядам и отнимаем одно значение од другого и записываем результат в 3-ю таблицу. Как то так:  `stg3.Cells[i,j] = stg1.Cells[i,j] - stg2.Cells[i,j]` [теория](https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/matrix/add_subtract/)

Comment: ну с дискретки есть скрипт на паскале, где идет плюс, минус, умножить и деление. пробовал его закинуть, но работает криво